# Running unit tests on more than five cores in parallel

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing

I've followed the instructions on [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vstsqualitytools/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpucore-machine) to the letter and I can execute tests in parallel.

So far so good.

Now the problem: I can't set the parallelTestCount to zero (Auto configure) or to a value above 5. Running five parallel tests works fine but not six.

Yes I have more than five cores on my machine; I am running on an Intel i7 processor which has four cores with hyperthreading meaning I should be able to run 8 tests in parallel.

Now I'm sure there are some other logical or hard limitations and I am not expecting to be able to run on eight cores lightning-speeding eight tests through in parallel.

However it would be cool to know the reason for it not running more than five tests in parallel?

Comment: When you say you can't set it to zero, what is preventing this?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Doh - I forgot to say! When I run the tests with the setting to 0 I get one test that is "Not Executed" and the other 7 immediately turn to "Aborted". There is no more info. When I set it to 6 funnily enough I get two tests that are "Not Executed" and the rest are "Aborted". Same with the setting to 7. With the setting to 8 I get all tests immediately "Aborted".

Comment: maybe try with just a simple set of tests that don't do anything spectacular so that you can figure out whether the problem is in the tests you're running or in the test framework itself?

Comment: That's just the thing... my eight different tests are test-tests. All they do is a simple Thread.Sleep(5000). In a perfect world my eight cores would execute them all at the same time. Question is why only five max? Is it a VS limitation or is it hardware or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in MSTest. I have stumbled upon the same problem, all tests are marked as aborted and there is a "Test run error" link in the Test Results window which if clicked yields this message: "Test run is aborting on '', number of hung tests exceeds maximum allowable '5'".

Update: It is fixed in the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack.

Comment: I can confirm that! Seems it is VS that is cutting us off!

Comment: Filed an issue on Microsoft Connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587386/running-more-than-five-tests-in-parallel-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

It could just be me but hyperthreading isn't a real core so an i7 only really has 4 physical cores not 8. Maybe it is something to do with that.

Or perhaps there is some bios setting relating to how the hyperthreading can be used by the OS that is preventing it.

Comment: You are likely right but how does that explain that I can easily run 5 tests and not only four?

Comment: I guess in theory the HT should allow more but perhaps there is something in the bios that limits how the HTs can be used and the current setting is what allows VS to do 5 but no more and changing it might allow for more.